# My win7 pro cannot enter safe mode

Tags: windows-7

When I press F8, I can select safe mode. However, after it finished loading and I enter the admin password, the computer restart so that I can't enter the safe mode. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: is your system damaged? can you boot normally?

Comment: I can boot normally and everything seems working well except a third party application. I want to enter the safe mode for troubleshooing.

Comment: run `sfc /scannow` from an elevated command prompt, to look for issues with your system binaries.

Comment: I performed sfc /scannow and found corrputted file which cannot be repaired automatically. I will follow up. Thanks